# Windows Universal App (XAML): ListviewItem on selected advanced view (Show button only when ListViewItemsis selected)

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, win-universal-app, windows-10

I'm working on my first Universal App (I'm beginner with it).

In app I have few places, where I want to select ListViewItem, and remove/edit (https://i.stack.imgur.com/qKiVF.png) it by some button. I'm not a designer, so I want to choose some simple, good-looking solution how to display these buttons.

I was inspired by Windows 10, there are few places, where you click on ListViewItem, and this selected item shows some buttons (Printer setting, WiFi connection, Bluetooth connection) - like on this image - https://i.stack.imgur.com/guiLR.png.

I've spend lot of time with googling, trying, and now I have no idea how to do it. I was closest probably with using VisualStateManager in ListViewItemContainer.

Here is code example (in c# is filled ItemsSource by some ObservableCollection<>):

```
<ListView Name="dbList" Grid.Column="0" SelectionChanged="dbList_SelectionChanged">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Name="XXX">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
                            <Button Name="removeDatabaseButton" Click="removeDatabaseButton_Click" Content="Remove" Tag="{Binding}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

Thanks!

PS: Sorry for my english :)

Comment: So what is the actual question? If you want xaml that ends up looking that the second screen shot you might want to consider using the new RelativePanel.

Comment: Yes, I want to create ListViewItemTemplate (in XAML) that works like ListViewItem on second image - so, I have button in all items, but they are not visible, and only when I select some element, the button change its visibility (or something like that). Or maybe it can be do by changing ListViewItem height, based on selection.

Comment: @LukasCaldr You mean if you click the listviewitem it should expend and as well show the button which has the property Visibility="Collapsed" if the user hasn't pressed the item, do you?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is quite complicated:

You need to modify your list Type Class which should implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface which has the property Visible.

```
 private Visibility _visible;

    public Visibility Visible //Binding to this in Listbox - Button Visibility
    {
        get { return _visible; }
        set { _visible = value; } //Call OnPropertyChanged method
    }
```

Now create a listview_itemclick() method. Call the listview.selectedindex and set the visibility of the listitem property "Visible" to Visible - the event PropertyChanged will fire and the ui gets notified that the visibility of this specific button should change.

Helping links:

[INotifyPropertyChangedInterface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

[Playlist to MVVM tutorials - containing INotifyPropertyChanged](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k77dqVVWgB8)